# Speeding up the calculation of a binomial sum

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, summation

Is it possible to speed up this calculation?

```
A[j_, p_, n_] := Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k), {k, 0, j}]
Plot[{A[j, 0.5, 12000]}, {j, 0, 12000}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica complains due to the occurence of very small numbers that cannot be represented in machine precision. However, the built-in cummulative distribution function (`CDF`) of the `BinomialDistribution` is sufficiently robust against that (replacing very small numbers simply by 0.).

```
A[j_, p_, n_] := CDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], j]
nn = 120;
Plot[{A[j, 0.5, nn]}, {j, 0, nn}]
```

[image]

```
nn = 12000;
Plot[{A[j, 0.5, nn]}, {j, 0, nn}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The summation can be evaluated to a closed form, which can speed up the further usage:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k), {k, 0, j}] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> (1 - p)^n ((1/(1 - p))^n - (1 - p)^(-1 - j) p^(1 + j)
>  Binomial[n, 1 + j] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + j - n, 2 + j, 
>  p/(-1 + p)])
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The expression inside the `Sum[]` is actually built into *Mathematica* as `BernsteinBasis[]`, which gets primarily used in the construction of Bézier curves. Applied to this situation, we have the formula

```
A[j_, p_, n_] := Sum[BernsteinBasis[n, k, p], {k, 0, j}, Method -> "Procedural"]
```

which ought to be very stable to evaluate. If needed, however, one can also implement the de Casteljau formula so that the Bernstein polynomials are recursively generated instead.

(back to *gedanken Mathematica*, so untested)